# How to get URL referer link within a site?

Tags: php, url, referer

For Example, I have two pages, 355 and 705, on the same domain, so when I click on "Go to page 705", to go to that page but that the referer be 705, as in the Example:

```
<A href="www.site.com/Contents.php?page=705&ref=335">Go to page 705</A>
```

I want that to be within the same domain. I have a web site which is an online encyclopedia, and I want to know from which page user went to some other page. I want the same for every page, that is why I need this within a domain.

Answer (score 1):

1) The separator for query string parameters is `&` not `?`
2) You need to provide a protocol if you're going to include your domain in the URL (http:// or https://)
3) Use `$_GET['page']` to get the new referral ID for your links

```
<A href="http://www.site.com/Contents.php?page=705&ref=<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>">Go to page 705</A>
```

Comment: I know, I fixed it just now. And what do you mean, what protocol? I need to do the requested with PHP.

Comment: Also remember to sanitize $_GET variables before echoing them to the browser.

Comment: Should replace that "page" with the actual page's name? I tested what you gave me, and this is what i got: [link]http://www.anony.ws/i/2014/04/09/HmzfK.jpg

Comment: Replace it with whatever array key/variable contains the value you want there

Comment: I don't understand... To replace it with page's name? Can I automatically get the page's name with the code while generating the referer? I added page's name to $_GET['...']; and I still get the ref= empty.

Comment: Somewhere you have the value you want to show in `ref=`. What is it called?

Comment: It is the previous page's name: Zero. So, in the next page's url to be: Term?which=One&ref=Zero

Comment: Do you have that name in a variable? If so, what is it called?

Comment: <?php
$phpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
switch($_GET['termin'])
{case 'Zero': include("Zero.html"); break;}
?>

Comment: Looks like you want to use `$_GET['termin']`

Comment: It works. Thank you. Can I now make some database of how many times certain page had such referals?

Comment: That's a whole other question!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you can do this:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/Contents.php?page=705&ref=<?php print $_GET['page']; ?>">Go to page 705</A>
```